# Why can't this function be overloaded with one of clearly different signature?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

The following code fails to compile because of `error: redefinition of ‘template<class Integer, class> void func(Integer)’`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Float, typename = typename 
std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Float>::value>::type>
void func(Float floatVal)
{
    std::cerr << "float: " << floatVal << "\n";
}

template<typename Integer, typename = typename 
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>::type>
void func(Integer integer)
{
    std::cerr << "integral: " << integer << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    func(32.4246);
    func(144532);
}
```

But the two functions will clearly have different signatures on template instantiation. So why is can't this compile?

**Please note**: I *do* know how to fix this: just adding another dummy template parameter to one of the functions, e.g. `typename=void`, will work, like here

```
template<typename Integer, typename dummy=void, typename = typename 
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>::type>
void func(Integer integer){}
```

But the question is *why* do I have to do this?

Comment: the problem is that you're defaulting the template type for the second template arg.

Comment: You can't give another template default parameter to other declarations in the same scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4527 §1.3.19 [defns.signature.templ]

> **signature**
>
> <function template> name, parameter type list (8.3.5), enclosing namespace (if any), return type, and
>   template parameter list

The default template argument is *not* part of the signature of a function template.

Answer (score 4):

You can change `std::enable_if<...>::type` as the return type of the function.  As far as I know you cannot pass it to the type of another template parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Float> 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Float>::value>::type
func(Float floatVal)
{
    std::cerr << "float: " << floatVal << "\n";
}

template<typename Integer>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>::type
func(Integer integer)
{
    std::cerr << "integral: " << integer << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    func(32.4246);
    func(144532);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fa29f4e6f06da7b)</kbd>

Comment: This won't work if the functions are constructors (my example was just simplified because the problem reproduces with free functions). Also, this doesn't answer _the_ question: "why?".

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to overloading on return type like [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31677067/27678) did, you can be a little more complicated in the template types:

```
template<typename Float, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Float>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void func(Float floatVal)
{
    std::cerr << "float: " << floatVal << "\n";
}

template<typename Integer, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<Integer>::value && std::is_integral<Integer>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void func(Integer integer)
{
    std::cerr << "integral: " << integer << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca7a83b1774cca47)
Notice that the second `enable_if` for `Integer` explicitly negates the `enable_if` condition for `Float`

The benefit of this approach is that your functions still return `void`

And test it:

```
int main()
{
    func(32.4246);
    func(144532);
}
```

Output:

```
float: 32.4246
integral: 144532
```